# AWS S3 Website Hosting - Url Redirect Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services

The below link mentions about redirection of a website hosted in S3 bucket.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html

I have a url like this  www.myurl.com. I want the below redirection

www.myurl.com to www.myurl.com\page\mainpage
www.myurl.com\page to www.myurl.com\page\mainpage

Question is whether  it is possible to do the above redirection. I have gone all through the documentation mentioned in the above link but not possible to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you should be able to do something like:

```
<RoutingRules>
 <RoutingRule>
  <Condition>
   <KeyPrefixEquals>/</KeyPrefixEquals>
  </Condition>
  <Redirect>
   <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>/mainpage/</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
  </Redirect>
 </RoutingRule>
 <RoutingRule>
  <Condition>
   <KeyPrefixEquals>page/</KeyPrefixEquals>
  </Condition>
  <Redirect>
   <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>/page/mainpage/</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
  </Redirect>
 </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

You would paste this XML in the input provided on that page.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But this is not working as expected. Reason being when you page/ with /page/mainpage/ it enters into a redirect loop. This issue I was also facing earlier. Any other suggegtions.

Comment: You would just have to play with the paths to get the right structure. Adding slashes, removing slashes, etc. This is a common issue with AWS documentation. They give a little bit, but then leave you to figure out the finite details. Overall, this is the correct way to solve your problem though.

Comment: I think it is not possible to do what I intend with the available features. I am still wondering how by adding , removing slashes I could get what I want as you mentioned

Comment: Well, you said you're getting a redirect loop which indicates it is  trying to redirect, just redirecting to the wrong location. As an alternative, you could just put an index.html file in the root path, then redirect using JavaScript.